# mysql getting records depending on the current day, week, month, year

Tags: mysql

I need a mysql statement to pull records depending on the current day, week, month, and year.

I have a column that's formatted as timestamp so I know I am good there.

Example:

```
$sql_total_users_week = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE reg_date = thisweek()";
$result_total_users_week = mysql_query($sql_total_users_week);
$records_total_users_week = mysql_num_rows($result_total_users_week);
```

for some reason the records are pulling by the day and not the week. Cant seem to figure out what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to take a look at the [MySQL date and time reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html).

Comment: Very Cool, trying to understand it. I have something like this so far, not working but maybe some light on the subject? SELECT * FROM users WHERE week(reg_date,3) = week(date(),3)

Comment: This worked "select YEARWEEK(`reg_date`) as theweek, count(*) FROM users group by theweek"